System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Name or service not known, when trying to MigrateAsync and running the app via docker-compose
I've created a hosted service that is supposed to apply migrations to postgres when app is starting:
internal class DatabaseInitializer : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<DatabaseInitializer> _logger;
    public DatabaseInitializer(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<DatabaseInitializer> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var dbContextTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(x => typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && x != typeof(DbContext));

        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        foreach (var dbContextType in dbContextTypes)
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(dbContextType) as DbContext;
            if (dbContext is null)
            {
                continue;
            }
                
            _logger.LogInformation($"Running DB context: {dbContext.GetType().Name}...");
            await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}

It works when I try to launch the app with IIS or https profile, all migrations are applied correctly. However I want to run this app with docker and for that purpose i've generated dockerfile and docker-compose file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Bootstrapper/AlledrogO.Bootstrapper/AlledrogO.Bootstrapper.csproj", "Bootstrapper/AlledrogO.Bootstrapper/"]
COPY ["Modules/AlledrogO.Post/AlledrogO.Post.Api/AlledrogO.Post.Api.csproj", "Modules/AlledrogO.Post/AlledrogO.Post.Api/"]
COPY ["Modules/AlledrogO.Post/AlledrogO.Post.Application/AlledrogO.Post.Application.csproj", "Modules/AlledrogO.Post/AlledrogO.Post.Application/"]
COPY ["Modules/AlledrogO.Post/AlledrogO.Post.Domain/AlledrogO.Post.Domain.csproj", "Modules/AlledrogO.Post/AlledrogO.Post.Domain/"]
COPY ["Shared/AlledrogO.Shared/AlledrogO.Shared.csproj", "Shared/AlledrogO.Shared/"]
COPY ["Modules/AlledrogO.Post/AlledrogO.Post.Infrastructure/AlledrogO.Post.Infrastructure.csproj", "Modules/AlledrogO.Post/AlledrogO.Post.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Modules/AlledrogO.User/AlledrogO.User.Api/AlledrogO.User.Api.csproj", "Modules/AlledrogO.User/AlledrogO.User.Api/"]
COPY ["Modules/AlledrogO.User/AlledrogO.User.Core/AlledrogO.User.Core.csproj", "Modules/AlledrogO.User/AlledrogO.User.Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Bootstrapper/AlledrogO.Bootstrapper/AlledrogO.Bootstrapper.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Bootstrapper/AlledrogO.Bootstrapper"
RUN dotnet build "AlledrogO.Bootstrapper.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "AlledrogO.Bootstrapper.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AlledrogO.Bootstrapper.dll"]

services:
  alledrogo.api:
    image: alledrogo.api
    container_name: Api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Bootstrapper/AlledrogO.Bootstrapper/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
  alledrogo.database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: Postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=alledrogo
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./.containers/alledrogo-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

When I run docker-compose up -d --build i recieve System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known.
This happens only when executing await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationToken);
Thanks for any help!
I've treid diffrent hosts in connection string, but none of them worked:

Host=postgres
Host=postgres:5432
Host=alledrogo.database
Host=alledrogo.database:5432
Host=localhost:5432


Does this answer your question? (setting up docker-compose version and hostname attribute).

Setting hostname explicity didn't help. I found out that wrapping the MigrateAsync in try/catch block can partially solve the problem: the exception is still thrown during image build, but after that I can rerun the container and the connection to Postgres works (and migrations are applied). It's a workaround, but I still don't understand why the code in IHostedService is running during build process.


It's a workaround, but I still don't understand why the code in IHostedService is running during build process

No code is executed during image build, probably your api container runs earlier than db-container. Docker-compose has depends_on attribute.
Two line fix:
alledrogo.api:
    image: alledrogo.api
    container_name: Api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Bootstrapper/AlledrogO.Bootstrapper/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    depends_on:
      - alledrogo.database

It should help.
Check the docs for this attribute, it has short and long syntax.
